How to fix decorator problem in mobx-react?
I have this problem with mobx react decorators, where I get syntax error in a browser.
How to avoid it?
  @computed get emailBody () {
    return generateTemplate(this.emailTitle, this.inputBody);
  };

I tried to edit config files of my react vite app, but nothing happenned.
I hope that I'll be able to correct this.

Please add more details, like showing your tsconfig.json and the error message.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Short Answer
try to enabling babel decorator plugin as described in docs https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html.
then try to set experimentalDecorators: true. (documentation say to set it false but true is work for me.
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* set true or false, true work for me */
  },
}

Long answer
recently i found similar issues, error only shown in browser console not inside vite dev command, error look like this 
my code look like this
import {
  action,
  computed,
  observable
} from "mobx";

export class Todo {
  @observable
  title: string = ""

  @observable
  finsihed: boolean = false

  @action
  toggle(): void {
    this.finsihed = !this.finsihed
  }

  @computed
  get getTitleWithMark() {
    return this.title + "!!"
  }
}



based on documentation: https://mobx.js.org/enabling-decorators.html
i add option to vite for enabling babel decorator plugin, and enabling experimentalDecorators on tsconfig.json
//tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true /* set true or false, true work for me */
  },
}

// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react, { Options } from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

const option: Options = {
  babel: {
    parserOpts: {
      plugins: [
        'decorators',
      ]
    }
  }
}
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(option)],
})


hopefully help someone.
